# How would I match two separate arrays filled with strings in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, string, xcode

I have these two arrays below and I want them to match with each other. If the first element has the number "333-333-3333" I want it to match with the first element in the other array which is "John". For example I want to return the string John when I enter the 333-333-3333 in a search field. Is it possible to do that if Im using an array?

```
let personName : [String] = ["John", "San", "Jim"]
let personNumber : [String] = ["333-333-3333", "111-111,1111", "222-222-2222"]
```

Comment: Where is this data coming from? Can you avoid having it in multiple arrays to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
let personName  = ["John", "San", "Jim"]
let personNumber  = ["333-333-3333", "111-111,1111", "222-222-2222"]
let search = "333-333-3333"
if let item = personNumber.firstIndex(of:search) {
    print(personName[item])
}
```

Or better  OOP soluntion

```
let arr = [Item(name: "John", number: "333-333-3333")]

if let item = arr.first(where: { $0.number == search }) {
    print(item.name)
}


struct Item{
    let name,number:String
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiple arrays are very bad. A much better solution is a struct which contains all information about one Person

```
struct Person {
    let name, number : String
}

let people = [Person(name: "John", number: "333-333-3333"),
              Person(name: "San", number: "111-111,1111"),
              Person(name: "Jim", number: "222-222-2222")]
```

And search

```
if let foundPerson = people.first(where: {$0.number == "333-333-3333"}) {
    print(foundPerson.name)
} else {
    print("Person not found")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the zip() function which is designed to merge two sequences into a single sequence of tuples.

```
let combined = zip(personName, personNumber)
```

If you print combined you’ll see it contains this array:

```
[("John", "333-333-3333"), ("San", "111-111,1111"), ("Jim", "222-222-2222")]
```

to find name for a specific number you can use

```
func getName(for number: String, combined: [(String, String)]) -> String? {
    return combined.first{ $0.1 == number }?.0
}

getName(for: "333-333-3333", combined: combined) // returns John
getName(for: "444-444-444", combined: combined) // returns nil
```

Comment: This answer solves the issue as required but of course using struct to wrap person details is much better as Vadian answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61067906/5278455